# Spring MVC jQuery redirect not works

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, redirect

I did a small controller with Spring MVC and JSP, that shows the list of Student objects. Also in this controller I did method to process POST request. POST method pass Student id parameter and controller should delete Student with this id.

This works fine, but after delete I want page to reload itself without user page reload click, but this is not work. I tried `"redirect:students"` in POST handler, and see in debugger it passes to GET method, but when I check get response in browser - it looks like Student not deleted, so page appears the same as it was before POST - this is the problem. When I reload page in browser it shows updated data (without deleted Student). POST method send through jQuery without form on page and I not use AJAX.

Please help to get refreshed page after POST request.

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("students");
    mv.addObject("studentsList", studentDAO.getStudents());
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteStudent(Model model, @RequestParam("id") String idString) {
    studentDAO.deleteStudent(Long.parseLong(idString));
    return "redirect:students";
}
```

JQuery post

```
$.post("deleteStudent",
        {id:$(this).children('.id').text()})
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/students.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Students list
</h1> 

    <div class="table">
        <div class="row studentsHeader">
            <div class="cell id">ID</div>
            <div class="cell">First Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Last Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Birth Date</div>
        </div>

        <c:if test="${not empty studentsList}">
            <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentsList}">
                <div class="row studentData">
                    <div class="cell id">${student.id}</div>                
                    <div class="cell firstName">${student.firstName}</div>
                    <div class="cell lastName">${student.lastName}</div>
                    <div class="cell birthdate"><fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${student.birthdate}" /></div>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/students.js" />"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var element=$(this).children('.id');
var jqxhr = $.post("deleteStudent",
    {id:$(element).text()}).done(function() {
            $(element).remove()
    });
```

This code will remove the student element when delete operation is successful.
In Controller code you don't have to write redirect and This method should return String data or some object which you can use in done method at client side to perform some logic.

Comment: No. This will not works. Think what if controller fails to delete, but on UI Student will be deleted? That is why I want to reload all page data.

Comment: That is why controller should return some string like "Success" or "Fail" with the help of which you can determine whether student is deleted or not . If response from controller is success then you will remove student else you will not remove student at client side